# share data between mobile devices on same wifi without the use of internet

Tags: flutter, dart, wifi, p2p

I am creating a app in which i need to share data between mobile devices on same wifi without the use of internet. I am using flutter. It is something like wifi-direct

Answer (score 0):

You could open a web server on each device and advertise it on the local network using something like [NDS](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd) on Android or [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/) on iOS. Then you just have to connect to the other device's server and can start sharing data over a standard TCP socket or whatever you end up using.

WiFi direct would probably work too, but is a lot more complicated and if both devices are already connected to the same network, you should leverage that.

Comment: Can You Please Tell me how to share data over a tcp socket in flutter